# pgAdmin4 - Created Table but Values Don't Appear in Table, Only the Column Names

Tags: pgadmin-4

In pgAdmin 4, in Objects panel on the left, I am clicking through Servers -> PostGreSQL 16 -> Databases -> analysis -> Schemas -> Public -> Tables and then creating a table named Teachers, a very small dataset with just six rows and a few columns.  I typed in the query and hit the Execute/Refresh button and got the message the table had been created.  Then right-clicked Teachers, the table name, then clicked View/Edit Data, then clicked All Rows.  The table appears with only the column attributes and outline of the table but does NOT include the values!  Next to the column attributes are the padlock symbol, but as a new user I don't know what that means or how to get past this and be able to view the full table.

I tried to fix the problem by right-clicking again on the Teachers table name, and selecting Properties, then Columns, then choosing Primary Key? for one of the columns (the column containing the common field to other tables concerning the teachers, the I.D. #).  As a new user, I didn't know which, if any, of the columns I should select as a Primary Key.  There were no Primary Keys selected previously, so I thought there should be one in order to allow the values to appear on the table.  Also, the same column had the Not Null? pre-selected, but no other columns were selected.  My only expectation was to have my table appear in its full version, values and all!